# Need to set the end of previous month in Power BI

Tags: date, powerbi-desktop

I have a Slicer in my Power BI Desktop Report which has date ranges -
**07-2015 thru 12-2050** (max date in my Database):

[image]

Using StackOverflow advice I was able to limit the Range to the current Month (08-2019), using the following formula

```
 IsToday = SWITCH (TRUE (),'Dimension Date'[Date] <= NOW (), 1, 0)
```

Now, my goal is to create a column, which will limit the current Month in my Slicer - **to the end of the Previous Month** (For example - if today is **08/21/2019** I need my Slicer (and Report's Data) to show until **07/31/2019**)

Ps-
I know the formula to show the end of previous Month out of the current Month.
I used -

```
  EOMONTH('Dimension Date'[Date],-1)
```

But still, have no idea how to make it appear in my Report, without the current date...

Please Help !

Comment: did you managed to solve it?

Comment: @AnkUser  - yes, created a column as advised below

Comment: Could you please mark answer as solved, it will help others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I added 2 new columns. `Column` will hold Current Date which will be used for our calculation.

`Calc` Column will return Date if currentdate-1 month is less than Date else it will return currentdate-1 months

Now you can use this `Calc` for your slicer and as you can see you will get only dates before currentdate-1 months

Below expressions were been used.

```
Column = DATE(YEAR(TODAY());MONTH(TODAY())-1;DAY(TODAY()))
calc = If('Table'[Column]>='Table'[Date];'Table'[Date].[Date];'Table'[Column].[Date])
```

Note: you can format how you wish to represent your dates in PoweBI Modelling tab.